# SphinxQL + sphinxsearch table doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Today I was trying to use sphinxsearch with SphinxQL but something going bad =\
First I installed sphinxsearch then I configured it, after that I created index forum_index using indexer --all. All finished without errors.
Then I included SphinxQl to my project, typed host and port which is listening sphinx and tried to make a query like in ReadMe of SphinxQL:

```
// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 9306))
;
```

But it caused a database access error:

```
access denied www-data@localhost password NO
```

After that I set parameters of username and password in SphinxQL using

```
 mysqli::real_connect()
```

Previous errors disappeared
Then I tried to make a test query:

```
$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('column_one', 'colume_two')
    ->from('forum_index');
$result = $query->execute();
```

But I get an error:

```
table forum_index doesn't exists
```

I have a feel that my SphinxQL doesn't see sphinx or sphinx config and tries to make a simple query.
Have you any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Set also the db name

Comment: already ( 15 symbols comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting host = '127.0.0.1' in SphinxQL params

Answer (score 0):

Please go to command line use the following command

```
mysql -P9306 --protocol=tcp --prompt='sphinxQL> '
```

Once get sphinxQL prompt enter the following command

```
sphinxQL> show tables;
```

If you set up everything correctly you can see the `forum_index` table in the list. Else check your searchd configuration section in your sphinx.conf file for proper configuration. My configuration look like this

```
searchd {
  listen                  = 9315
  listen                  = 9306:mysql41
  log                     = /Users/XXXX/projects/sphinx/data/searchd.log
  query_log               = /Users/XXXX/projects/sphinx/data/query.log
  read_timeout            = 5
  max_children            = 30
  pid_file                = /Users/XXXX/projects/sphinx/data/searchd.pid
  max_matches             = 1000
  seamless_rotate         = 1
  preopen_indexes         = 0
  unlink_old              = 1
  workers                 = threads
  thread_stack            = 1024K
}
```

Comment: it works, but it is another story =) above solution of my problem